# Angular websocket is not working with Azure VM nginx on production but works in local

Tags: javascript, azure, websocket, nestjs, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am posting this after spending almost an entire week on this issue, and I could not fix the same.

I am trying to implement a notification service with the client as an Angular application, and my backend is in NodeJS - NestJS framework. I have a VM server running on Azure with Nginx.

It is perfectly working on my local, but when I deploy my code to the server, I always get this error:

> websocket.js:54 WebSocket connection to 'ws://domain.com/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:

What I have done so far:

1. I first thought the problem was with the code or SSL, but even without SSL, I am getting the same error. And code for the socket is executing fine in the local.
2. Then I felt the problem is with Nginx, and I have gone through different websites and solutions of other people for similar issues, but I don't see anything wrong with my Nginx. So here is what my Nginx looks like:

```
server {
        server_name domain.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        // I have removed ssl configuration for now. 
}
```

3. I somewhere read that we need to allow azure to accept socket connection. But those are related to the App Services. I have a VM instance running on the server, and I don't see anything wrong with azure configuration or NSG. I have a subscription offered by azure, and I am not using free services.

If you have something else that I should try, please suggest it. The code seems fine as I can execute socket connection on my local machine but not on the server.
I am looking forward to great minds guiding me with this. Sorry, If I am doing/missing something silly above.

Also, please let me know if you need more details on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- WebSocket are available in nginx from version 1.3.13
- Also set the `proxy pass` to your domain for e.g.: `http://websocket;` also if there are multiple address mapped to the domain the nginx will go through all of them.
- Also set the `proxy_set_header Connection`   as  `$connection_upgrade;` just like the `$http_upgrade` in  `proxy_set_header Upgrade` .

So the nginx should look like this

```js
server {
        server_name domain.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://websocket;
                proxy_http_version 1.3.13;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        // I have removed ssl configuration for now. 
}
```

Refer the following [Nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) on proxy pass

Also refer this [article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-configure-nginx-as-reverse-proxy-for-websocket#:%7E:text=NGINX%20supports%20WebSocket%20by%20allowing%20a%20tunnel%20to,deals%20with%20this%20as%20a%20WebSocket%20connection.%20) by Sharon Chirstine